# split the screen into two parts

Tags: android

I need to split the Android screen into two parts and run 2 
applications (app A and app B) simultaneously. 
App A will run on screen 1 and App B will run on screen 2. Both are visible to the 
users. I need to implement this thing in the Android Framework. 
I do not know much about the android framework and this is urgent and should be done on android 2.1
Is this possible, if yes please explain the procedure to achieve this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: 1) Is this homework? If so, you should mark the question as such by adding a tag. 2) You're asking for something rather complicated - you can't just do something like that without knowing much about the platform. 3) Are apps A and B meant to be anything the user decides including external apps (i.e. is this more of a framework app that lets the user launch things), or are they activities internal to your application?

Comment: What you want is impossible without modifying the firmware -- sorry!

Comment: Thatnks for comment.
The apps are external and this is not a homework. I am trying to achieve this through the android frame work but unable to find the exact things that i need to do.

Comment: The solution is mentioned [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3968171/android-split-the-screen-in-2-equals-parts-with-2-listviews) as well.

Answer (score 1):

Implement Application A as a `ActivityGroup` and run Applicatoin B inside of it.

Comment: That will not work. You cannot use `ActivityGroup` to run multiple applications.

Comment: Both the applications are external i.e., those are selected by the user.

Comment: @CommonsWare: I know, that's why Aplication A should be one of both activities to run. So one of the activities he wants to run is the ActivityGroup. So you are running the ActivityGroup (app A) and Application B in the ActivityGroup.
N G Kishore, ok no luck then.