# How to display the result of two diffrent activities in the same xml view

Tags: android, xml, listview, xml-parsing

I'm trying to combine two listviews in the same view(main.xml),I'm trying to  follow [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3968171/android-split-the-screen-in-2-equals-parts-with-2-listviews),however the result of only one activity is always displayed in my case.

Here is my main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:weightSum="2" >

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ListView
        android:id="@android:id/list"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" />
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/list1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Clear Cache" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: have you tried setting the listviews android:layout_height to wrap?

Comment: @Bill Gary,yes that is correct but i'm still getting one view displayed.I suspect that the other view is behind the displayed view