# 3 vertical listViews in one scrollview

Tags: android, listview, android-listview, android-scrollview

I need to implement such a screen :

[image]

So, I've created the adapter with ImageView, 2 TextViews and CheckBox.

I need to implement 3 listViews and make the screen scrollable.

I tried to implemen the [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3968171/android-split-the-screen-in-2-equals-parts-with-2-listviews), but that is not workable for me - so I made like this :

```
  <ScrollView
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:fillViewport="true"
        android:orientation = "vertical" android:layout_height="match_parent">

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:weightSum="1.0"
        >
    <LinearLayout android:layout_weight="0.5"
                  android:orientation="vertical"
                  android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                  android:layout_width="fill_parent">
        <TextView
                android:text="@string/textview_settings_categories"
                style="@style/settings_label"/>
        <ListView   android:id="@+id/listView1"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent">

        </ListView>
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout android:layout_weight="0.25"
                  android:orientation="vertical"
                  android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                  android:layout_width="fill_parent">
        <TextView
                android:text="@string/textview_settings_categories"
                style="@style/settings_label"/>
    <ListView   android:id="@+id/listView2"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent">

    </ListView>
    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout android:layout_weight="0.25"
                  android:orientation="vertical"
                  android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                  android:layout_width="fill_parent">
        <TextView
                android:text="@string/textview_settings_categories"
                style="@style/settings_label"/>
        <ListView   android:id="@+id/listView3"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent">

        </ListView>
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

I also tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17693578/android-how-to-display-2-listviews-in-one-activity-one-after-the-other) one solution, but both not workable for me - the ScrollView can't be scrollable.

I also tried to implement 3 vertical ListFragments one above another, listviews are scrollable inside, but the scrollview is not - so I can't see the bottom of the screen.

Comment: Can't have ListView in ScrollView. Use ONE ListView and inflate different views for each row.

Comment: Agreed. Or, use one `ListView` and my `MergeAdapter`: https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-merge. This is very similar to a preference screen, which is implemented as a single `ListView` regardless of what its contents wind up being.

Comment: @Carnal , you CAN have a listview inside a scrollview. Yes, it's not best practice and probably not the best way to implement it, but you can do it. Don't just simply say, "Can't have ListView in ScrollView." See my answer below.

Answer (score 1):

It's not the best practice, but if you **really** want that functionality, you can just disallow the touch event of the parent scrollview once you touch it and re allow it once you leave the child container.

This is how I have done it before, where "listScanners" is my listview:

```
listScanners.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener()
{
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event)
        {
          v.getParent().requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(true);
          return false;
        }
    });
```

And this is the part of my layout that is relevant to the question:

```
 /* Theres more before this ... */
 <ScrollView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:scrollbarSize="0dp" >

        <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent">

                <RelativeLayout
                        android:orientation="vertical"
                        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                        android:layout_gravity="center"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:background="@null"
                        >
                    <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/emptylist1"
                            android:layout_width="450dp"
                            android:layout_height="80dp"
                            android:textColor="#6f6f6f"
                            android:textSize="20sp"
                            android:padding="3dp"
                            android:layout_marginBottom="3dp"
                            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                            android:text="No Scanners have been added..."/>
                    <ListView
                            android:id="@+id/listview_scanners"
                            android:layout_width="450dp"
                            android:layout_height="80dp"
                            android:padding="3dp"
                            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
                            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                            android:cacheColorHint="#00000000"
                            android:divider="#DEDEDE"
                            android:dividerHeight="1px">
                    </ListView>
                </RelativeLayout>
    /* Theres more after this ... */
```

## Correct Way:


Ideally you should rather have something like this, where your layout looks like this:

Where it is very important to have this in your linear layout:

```
android:isScrollContainer="true"
```

isScrollContainer means that the linearlayout contains a view that scrolls, meaning that it can be a certain size within the linear layout, however, it may contain much more when you scroll it. Here is the layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          android:orientation="vertical"
          android:layout_width="fill_parent"
          android:layout_height="fill_parent"
          android:background="#afafaf"
          android:isScrollContainer="true">
 <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:background="#FF63FF9B"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        >

    <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textview_heading"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="25sp"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:textColor="#ffffff"
            android:text="View First List"/>
</LinearLayout>

<RelativeLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="150dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:background="@null"
        >
    <ListView
            android:id="@+id/listview1"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="130dp"
            android:cacheColorHint="#00000000"
            android:divider="#DEDEDE"
            android:dividerHeight="1px">
    </ListView>
</RelativeLayout>
<LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:background="#FF63FF9B"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        >

    <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textview_heading"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="25sp"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:textColor="#ffffff"
            android:text="View Second List"/>
</LinearLayout>

<RelativeLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="150dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:background="@null"
        >
    <ListView
            android:id="@+id/listview2"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="130dp"
            android:cacheColorHint="#00000000"
            android:divider="#DEDEDE"
            android:dividerHeight="1px">
    </ListView>
</RelativeLayout>

<LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:background="#FF63FF9B"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        >

    <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textview_heading"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="25sp"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:textColor="#ffffff"
            android:text="View Third List"/>
</LinearLayout>

<RelativeLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="150dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:background="@null"
        >
    <ListView
            android:id="@+id/listview3"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="130dp"
            android:cacheColorHint="#00000000"
            android:divider="#DEDEDE"
            android:dividerHeight="1px">
    </ListView>
</RelativeLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

I just made this in 5 minutes and you get a layout looking like this: (this is just a draft, obviously just to give you an idea)

[image: Your layout with listviews]

And last but not least, in your code where you display the lists, you will have something like this:

```
public class Screen_View_Lists extends Activity
{
    BaseAdapter                 listAdapter;
    ListView                    list1,list2,list3;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle icicle)
    {
        super.onCreate(icicle);
        setContentView(R.layout.screen_view_packages);

       list1 = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listview1);
       list2 = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listview2);
       list2 = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listview3);

       listAdapter = new Adapter_List_Main(this, packages);//This is my own adapter, you probably use your own custom one as well.
       list1.setAdapter(listAdapter);

      //Setup list to support context menu
      registerForContextMenu(list1);

      //Setup list to support long click events.
      list1.setLongClickable(true);

      //Action Listener for long click on item in the list
      list1.setOnItemLongClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener()
      {
        public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position, long id)
        {
            //do things here       

        }
    });

    //Action Listener for short click on item in the list
    list1.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener()
    {
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position, long id)
        {
            //do things here
        }
    });

    //And so one . . . 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to have a better look at the documentation of [ListView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ListView.html) or if you want to work a little bit more to [RecyclerView](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.html). The latter one will allow you definitely more flexibility and maintainability.

Anyway, a base solution, that flattens a little bit your UI hierarchy is to use only one ListView/RecyclerView. Then in your adapter you can decide the type of view that your container is going to present.
In your design I'd identify 2 types:

- TYPE_HEADER
- TYPE_CHECKBOX

Once you have this things in place in your getView(...) you can decide based on the position and type what view instantiate(have a look at how to reuse them efficiently) and bind.

If you can try to avoid complexities those will become impossible to maintain :)

Comment: That RecyclerView looks promising ! Since the list he is going to display is definately not going to fit in the screen and also because of the multiple lists.

Comment: Also, the RecycledViewPool looks like a good idea if you are going to use 3 lists or RecycledViews that looks and behaves similar. https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.RecycledViewPool.html